# Declaration of the custom Signals

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In Qt, we can create custom signals by making them static variables. and then we use `self.signame` instead `classname.signame`.
So that creates an instance variable in the class.

I wanted to know the theory beyond this pattern.

here's some pseudo-code that I have tried that was recorded in most of the sources:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore
class test(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    sig=QtCore.pyqtSignal([bool])
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__([])
        # self.sig=QtCore.pyqtSignal([bool]) #1
        self.window=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.sig.connect(lambda x=True:print('Hello World'))
        self.bt=QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.window,text='test',clicked=self.sig)
        self.window.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.window.layout().addWidget(self.bt)
        self.window.show()
test().exec()
```

When i tred to access the signal `test.sig` instead of `self.sig` ,

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore
class test(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__([])
        self.sig=QtCore.pyqtSignal([bool])
        self.window=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.sig.connect(lambda x=True:print('Hello World'))
        self.bt=QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.window,text='test',clicked=self.sig)
        self.window.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.window.layout().addWidget(self.bt)
        self.window.show()
test().exec()
```

i get this error:

```
    test.sig.connect(lambda x=True:print('Hello World'))
AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

and when I tried to make the signal as an instance variable instead of the static variable I get that error (uncommenting the #1 in psudeo code)

I get the same error (as before).

May I know the reason behind this

Source: [PyQt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html)

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have edited a bit. guess it's okay for now.

Comment: I have used this code and I am not getting any problems. Note: the error message would never match the code you provide, are you sure that this error message is obtained with the code you provide?

Comment: the given pseudo code works without any error  but if we modify a bit by uncommenting #1 and removing the static variable, we get the error. I will add more code

Comment: mmm, why do you want to declare a signal as an attribute if PyQt clearly doesn't recommend it?

Comment: They haven't specifically discouraged other methods. So maybe as a beginner, it would be good for one to know about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted that pyqtSignal is declared as an attribute of the class but it is not the same object that is used in the connection as indicated in [the docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html):

> A signal (specifically an unbound signal) is a class attribute. When a
> signal is referenced as an attribute of an instance of the class then
> PyQt5 automatically binds the instance to the signal in order to
> create a bound signal. This is the same mechanism that Python itself
> uses to create bound methods from class functions.
>
> A bound signal has connect(), disconnect() and emit() methods that
> implement the associated functionality. It also has a signal attribute
> that is the signature of the signal that would be returned by Qt’s
> SIGNAL() macro.

In other words, `sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal([bool])` is an unbound signal but `self.sig` is the bound signal and that can be verified with the following lines:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class test(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal([bool])

    print(type(sig))

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__([])
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        print(type(self.sig))
        self.sig.connect(lambda x=True: print("Hello World"))
        self.bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.window, text="test", clicked=self.sig)
        self.window.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.window.layout().addWidget(self.bt)
        self.window.show()


test().exec()
```

Output

```
<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal'>
<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal'>
```

In conclusion, the attribute of the class "sig" is a pyqtSignal that does not have the connect method and that is used to construct the attribute "self.x" which is a pyqtBoundSignal that does have the connect method.

Comment: Thanks now I get it.  So objects can have different bound signals (bounded to diff. function)  of the same unbound signal

Comment: Don't get confused by the meaning of [un]bound: the word is not referred to what the signal is connected to, but to the binding *with the instance*. All signals can be connected to different functions (and to the same function more than once also, which is something that should be avoided if not for very specific reasons)